# Javascript calling variable across modules using click event

Tags: javascript, function, module, addeventlistener

newbie Javscripter here. I'm trying to get some practice with modules and I'm hitting a wall. I'm trying to get the `controller` module to access the `wagerAmount`(input by user) from the `UIControl` module with minimal success. My relevant code is as follows:

```
var UIControl = (function() {
  return {
    getWager: function() {
      return {
          wagerAmount: document.getElementById('wager').value
      };
    }
  };
})();


var controller = (function(UICont) {
  var topics = ['sports', 'history', 'technology', 'music', 'movies'];
  var wager = UICont.getWager();

  var changeClass = function() {
    document.getElementById('bet').addEventListener('click', function() {
      console.log(wager);
      for (var i = 0; i < topics.length; i++) {
        if (document.getElementById(topics[i]).classList[1] == 'select') {
                activateAnswers();
            }
        }
    });
  }
})(UIControl);
```

When I run this, `console.log(wager)` prints a empty string, `{wagerAmount: ""}`. If I declare `wager` inside the `changeClass` function, the same thing happens. However, if I declare `wager` inside the click event, it prints the number input by the user. BUT, the `topics` variable, declared in the `controller` is being accessed just fine by the click event. The main problem here is when I need to add the functionality to multiple click events, I would have to declare a new variable in each click event to access the same function, which sounds like bad practice. So what's going on here?

Comment: The code at the module level and the code in the event handler are running at different times - and therefore produce different values for an input that changes.

Comment: No, there's no problem with creating new local variables that you just need for the current task in a function.

Comment: thanks for the input guys. I found some sort of workaround or solution that I posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after spending a couple hours last night trying to figure this out, I quickly figured out the solution this morning after some coffee. In case anyone else has this problem I'll post my solution, and if someone else comes up with something else, they can post as well.

Instead of declaring `wager` in the `controller` anywhere, I created a new function inside `controller`:

```
var retrieveWager = function() {
    return {
        wager: UICont.getWager().wagerAmount
    };
}
```

and then could access it in any of the click events like this:

```
retrieveWager().wager;
```